# Facing some issues in creating function for next button to change section in a single webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a **next button** which will be **triggered to change a section in a single tab**. Steps I am using: 1st I need to get the url of the current tab and apply if condition to that url to check whether I should go to next section or not. If true then I will use the id in that url along with `triggerClick` event  `idtriggerClick`

**Code:**

```
var currentURL = window.location.href;
if(currentURL =="http://localhost/xyz/store?id=7"){
    id.trigger('click') //Now how to move onto the next section after an event is triggered.
}
else
```

Comment: you can use a function with parameters from the if condition

Comment: What do you mean the url of the current tab? Are you trying to get the id from the url? If so see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript - If you're stuck on something else, please elaborate.

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: I can't use window.location.href to store the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without specifying id in url. You need to use javascript/jquery for this. Below are reference steps to achieve this.

Javascript has **windows** *global object*, you can create your custom object inside it at very beginning of your code.

```
window.customobject = {
        step_one : true;
        step_two : false;
};
```

Trigger a button click and update step object.

```
jQuery('#buttonId').click(function(e){
     window.customobject.step_one = false;
     window.customobject.step_two = true;
});
```

Check the step object and update the section in your webpage.

```
jQuery('#buttonId').click(function(e){
         window.customobject.step_one = false;
         window.customobject.step_two = true;
         if(window.customobject.step_two){
            //Update your content section
         }  
});
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks

Comment: What is the meaning or use of parameter 'e' that is passed inside a function.

Comment: It's click event object. We have bind click event in "#buttonId", So when we click on this button, click event is fired and "e" is object of that click event. It's passed in function If inside the function definition we want to use of event object.